# Синтаксис String в SQlite

Tags: строки, sqlite, syntax

В таблицу БД, пусть имя таблицы будет example', я добавляю String(VARCHAR), пусть его значение будет 'kk'kk'. Проблема в том, что я не могу в String использовать зарезервированные слова и символы, в данном случае это '. Я же хочу спокойно использовать любые символы и словосочетания. Мне нужно что-то похожее на [] между именем таблицы, т.е. `create table [любой текст включая зарезервированные слова и спец. символы '''?$12](...)`. В имени таблицы [] помогают использовать любые символы, но вот с varchar у меня не прокатило.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Comment: при самостоятельном написании запросов используй одинарные кавычки; внутренние кавычки экранируй вручную. При получении строк от пользователя — эскейпь/квотируй средствами API sqlite'а того языка на котором пишешь....

Comment: @Fat-Zer если бы дело было только в одинарных кавычках, то я бы просто заменял их в строке на 2 одинарные кавычки, но т.к. это не только одинарные кавычки, а ещё 124 ключевых слова и другие спец. символы, то был бы идеально, если бы существовала альтернатива [tablename]  для строк

Comment: @ProstoCoder, а есть пример корректного запроса, в котором ключевое слово `'key'` стоит в контексте где допускается строка и интерпретируется как ключевое слово, а не как строка? или это для самоконтроля?

Comment: Вот пример: допустим у нас БД используется для хранения файловой системы, допустим мы решили добавить новый файл в определённую папку, пусть она называется 'MyFolder', а имя создаваемого файла будет 'Don't open me', тогда запрос будет выглядеть примерное так: insert into [MyFolder] (fileName, fileExtension) values ('Don't open me', 'txt'); В итоге у нас будет ошибка синтаксиса из-за ' в слове don't. Надо ставить два ' т.е. чтобы имя файла было 'Don''t open me'. Но проблема в том, что вдруг пользователь захочет употребить друге зарезервированные символы и будет ошибка синтаксиса.

Comment: @Fat-Zer и в итоге все случаи я не смогу предусмотреть, а ошибку избегать надо. В имени таблицы, если использовать знаки [] в начале и в конце имени соответственно, ошибки синтаксиса возникать не будет. А вот для строк я никак решения найти не могу, похожего на это, хотя полагаю, что оно должно быть

Comment: @ProstoCoder, не пойму, зачем тебе спецсимволы в именах таблиц — вероятно ты делаешь что-то не так... но вот одинарных кавычек для квотирования более чем достаточно — возможно ты просто не слышал про bind'ы — добавил ответом... ЗЫ: если всё так, то добавь пример запроса в вопрос...

Comment: Совершенно не важно, есть ключевые слова в имени колонки или нет. Просто [экранируйте](https://blog.christosoft.de/2012/10/sqlite-escaping-table-acolumn-names/) их двойными кавычками и всё! Единственно, что ещё нужно, удвоить кавычки внутри.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov проблема была не в названии колонок, а в значении, которое заносилось в неё. В моём случае это был String, но всё равно спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Символов для квотирования строковых литералов помимо одинарных кавычек`''` в sqlite [нет](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).

И они не нужны: при ручном вводе запроса расставлять кавычки — обязанность того кто взаимодействует с БД, а при получении данных от пользователя надо пользоваться семейством [bind-функций](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html). Они сами позаботится об экранировании и подборе кавычек для всего что может быть в строке. Эти функции есть в любой реализации API библиотеки и биндингов. Пример для запроса выше на Си:

```
// Данные полученные от пользователя:
char *filename = "Don't open me";
char *extention = "txt";

// ...

int rc;
sqlite3_stmt *stmt = NULL;

rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2 (db, 
    "INSERT INTO my_dir (fileName, fileExtension) values (?1, ?2)",
    -1, &stmt, NULL);
// в реальном коде подразумевается нормальная обработка ошибок
assert (rc == SQLITE_OK && stmt);
rc = sqlite3_bind_text (stmt, 1, filename, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);                                         
assert (rc == SQLITE_OK);
rc = sqlite3_bind_text (stmt, 1, extention, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);                                         assert (rc == SQLITE_OK);
rc = sqlite3_step (stmt); 
assert (rc == SQLITE_DONE);

sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

Да, имена таблиц таким образом подставлять не получится.

Comment: Это мне помогло, я просто создал PreparedStatement и в нём установил параметры методом preparedStatement.setString(1, "Don't open me"); и всё заработало как надо, спасибо